# django rest's viewset calls default serializer's create method instead of overriden method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a nested serializer with overridden create method:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data_model=Order
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['uid', 'user','price']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data=validated_data.pop('user')
        order=self.data_model.objects.create(**validated_data)
        order.user=self.context['request'].user
        order.save()
        return order

class LifeOrderSerializer(OrderSerializer):
   data_model =LifeOrder

   class Meta(OrderSerializer.Meta):
       model = LifeOrder
       fields = OrderSerializer.Meta.fields + [ "birth_year",
                                            "contract_duration",]
```

and in the views.py

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset_model = LifeOrder
    serializer_class = LifeOrderSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
            self.queryset_model.objects.all()
```

but when I send a post request to create , model serializers defualt create method gets called! what is the problem?

Comment: How did you make sure that the default create() was called?

Comment: by checking the break point in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ModelViewSet's CreateModelMixin that raised the exception before calling my own create function.
I ovveride create of modelview set and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

The serializer_class mentioned in the viewset is `LifeOrderSerializer`, I think it must be `OrderSerializer`, since that is the serializer where the `create()` is overridden.

In the case where `LifeOrderSerializer` is the child of `OrderSerializer`, please make sure that you have overridden the `create()` method of `LifeOrderSerializer` to make it work.

Something like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    order = super(OrderSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    return order
```

Comment: it's the parent of this serializer, I forgot to add that

Comment: Updated the answer.